# How can i find the exact location of a CSS code

Tags: css

I inspect the asset that I want to make modifications. However, I see the location of the code as the screenshot.

The problem is that there is no CSS file which named d61a6.css in my theme files.

How should I locate the file of that code?

Thanks

[image: imgurimage]

Comment: Look at the top right corner. Filename and Line is given. `d61a6.css at line 13`. You even can just click on it. To find the original files, you must provide sourcemaps.

Comment: It is directing a CSS code file within this URL `sitename.com/min/d61a6.css` but the problem is that there is no such a directory on my FTP.

Comment: I bet, there is. The browser does not create its own. Any kind of CSS compressor or compiler will create that. It also could be included by a javascript library?

Answer (score 1):

Usualy the link with `<filename>:<line>` should lead to that file, did you try clicking on it?
Ive highlighted it in yellow.
[image: Higlighted in yellow]

Comment: Yes it is directing a code file, however, i couldn't find it on my FTP.